# C# mpeg4 modify frames

Tags: c#, mpeg-4

Target is to add noize to every frame of mpeg4 video. Algo is a simply color modification for every pixel in frame for example.
So the question is how to solve it using .net (C#)? The program needed to read frame frame from input file, modify it and save to output file (for every frame of videofile).
Possible exists some free libraries  for mpeg-4 modification?

Regards!

Comment: Unless you know how to re-compress the file your file size is going to explode - just one of many facets to your problem.

Comment: Check out [DirectShow.NET](http://directshownet.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: Yes, I need to: decompress->modify->compress. File is MPG4 encoded by ffmpeg or xvid. I think MPG4 is standard format for any codec? or not?